# Making Candlestick graph with python

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I am a beginner in python trying to plot candlestick chart of stocks but am unable to do so. Matplotlib offers all charts except candlesticks. Any suggestions as to how i can achieve the results?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejDLH.png)

Comment: Please post your table in text format so other can replicate it easily. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The [mplfinace](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) library, originally a part of matplotlib but now independent and standalone, is an excellent tool for visualizing stock prices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import [this library](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) with pandas and use as the example below. Then you will be able to perform some candlestick plots.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

fig.show()
```